# What is a Fibre Channel disk?

Tags: storage, sas, sata, fibre-channel, netapp

Our NetAPP SAN uses something called "Fibre Channel" disks.

What are Fibre Channel disks, and does this mean that I can't replace them with a NetApp SATA or SAS disk?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask NetApp.

Comment: Fibre Channel is a storage interface, like SAS, SATA, SCSI, IDE.... None of these are blindly interchangeable (though **some** can emulate others and interposers can generally translate one to another at the disk interface).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a hard disk with a FC interface.

Nope, you probably can't just arbitrarily replace one of them with a disk with a different interface, and different IO characteristics, especially in a storage array. But ask your vendor to be certain, or consult their documentation!